# Mutually exclusive tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging, cleanup

There are some instances of mutually exclusive tags being used in questions:

[Foundation & Enterprise](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint-enterprise+sharepoint-foundation) ~ 60

[2007 & 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2007+2010) ~ 40

What's the best approach for dealing with this? Is there some way to automatically prevent it from happening, or is this a matter of manual cleanup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Foundation & Enterprise" is surely redundant - we should get rid of both tags.

"2007 & 2010" - might make sense if the question applies only to these two specific versions, although I suspect they should not be there. In general the version tags should only be used for a question that is specific to that version, if used at all. They tend to get mis-used.

Pretty sure the only solution is manual edits.

Comment: I'd vote for Foundation & Enterprise to be deleted. Also anything with both versions specified... just remove both version tags.

Comment: Also, I'm killing [tag:spapi]

Comment: I think there are instances where they're useful, but they're usually being misused as replacements for "sharepoint". The problems they cause seem to outweigh the benefit they bring, much like the version tags.

Comment: Yup, there is an element of looking for an easy tag, rather than thinking about the subject and tagging accordingly. Getting content owners to add metadata is a problem, as we SharePoint people know well.

Comment: There's also a precedent for deleting edition tags: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/297/should-we-have-tags-by-product-edition